# How to disable output on one of containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, codeship

I am using Codeship CI for my project.
I have selenium tests and I am using remote browser from `selenium/standalone-firefox` but it's producing tons of logs, so **I want to disable stdout for `selenium/standalone-firefox` container**.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Depending on the docker-compose version, can you use "log_driver: none", or "logging: \ driver: none" ? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/logging

Comment: Even using log_driver:none I get same output on stdout

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this approach:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dselenium.LOGGER.level=WARNING
```

Added it as ENV variables in docker image for `selenium/standalone-chrome`.

Comment: The only approach that works is to quiet the logs in the containerized application, like in the example above.

Answer (score 49):

Use `--log-driver=none` in `docker run`:

```
docker run -d --log-driver=none selenium/standalone-firefox
```

Or docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  selenium:
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    logging:
      driver: "none"

    image:
      selenium/standalone-firefox
```

You can also send the log to a file using:

```
docker run -d --log-driver=none -e SE_OPTS="log log.txt" selenium/standalone-firefox
```

Or docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  selenium:
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    environment:
      - SE_OPTS="log log.txt"

    image:
      selenium/standalone-firefox
```

For docker-compose file version 1 there is no other way than modifying the `entry_point.sh`

put this file next your docker-compose.yml `entry_point.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/bin/functions.sh

export GEOMETRY="$SCREEN_WIDTH""x""$SCREEN_HEIGHT""x""$SCREEN_DEPTH"

function shutdown {
  kill -s SIGTERM $NODE_PID
  wait $NODE_PID
}

if [ ! -z "$SE_OPTS" ]; then
  echo "appending selenium options: ${SE_OPTS}"
fi

SERVERNUM=$(get_server_num)
xvfb-run -n $SERVERNUM --server-args="-screen 0 $GEOMETRY -ac +extension RANDR" \
  java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar \
  ${SE_OPTS} >/dev/null &
NODE_PID=$!

trap shutdown SIGTERM SIGINT
wait $NODE_PID
```

The use this `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
selenium:
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"

  volumes:
    - .:/mnt
  image:
    selenium/standalone-firefox
  command: bash /mnt/entry_point.sh >/dev/null
```

Regards

Comment: Sorry, but didn't help :(

Comment: Just check if you are using the latest `docker-compose` version and also check if your `docker-compose.yml` begins with `version: '2'`

Comment: I cannot usre version: '2' because of codeship, already tried with log_driver in v1

Comment: Well forget about docker-compose and do it by hand with docker run

Comment: I cannot, because I prepare only yaml file that is run after pushing to branch, all I can modify is this pseudo docker-compose

Comment: I modified my answer to include the solution for version 1 docker-compose

Comment: Unforunately it's not working, used this like this: ```selenium_firefox:
  image: selenium/standalone-firefox
  ports:
    - 4444:4444
  environment:
    - SE_OPTS= >/dev/null
  command: bash /opt/bin/entry_point.sh >/dev/null 2>&1```

Comment: You skipped the volumes part. Check the docker-compose.yml is at the bottom of the answer. Entry_point.sh needs to be changed because it executes java with an & at the end. So stdout redirection in command is useless

Answer (score 3):

CodeShip uses a custom variant of docker-compose v1 that accepts an environment setting.  The following in codeship-services.yml worked for me:

```
selenium:
  image: selenium/standalone-chrome
  cached: true
  container_name: selenium
  environment:
    -  SE_OPTS=-log /tmp/log.txt
```

The SE_OPTS value should not be in quotes.  /tmp is writeable, other locations may result in a permission error.

Answer (score 0):

Now with Docker Compose v2 you can remove the `version` top-level configuration. It enables Compose Specification as Docker Compose "version" (see "Warning" on [the related doc page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/) ). The Specification allows to use [the "attach" configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#attach).

In your case you can achieve what you wan by the following docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  selenium:
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    attach: false

    image:
      selenium/standalone-firefox
```

**Warning:** Note that there is no `version` key here. It is important. Also note that Docker Compose v2 command is `docker compose` (so please, do NOT use `docker-compose` command with this file).

*Alternative way*
With Docker Compose v2 you can see output for only selected service like this:

```
docker compose up --attach service_with_useful_output
```

**Warning:** Do not use this flag with Docker Compose v1 (`docker-compose`) for this purpose because `docker-compose up --attach service_with_useful_output` works differently.